# Can I use "token pasting operator" with 'const' template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, arguments

I'm trying to write a generic class for the microcontroller I'm using. It's not rare that these beasts use registers in the form `<register prefix> <index> <suffix>`, such as `UCSR0B` or `TCCR1A`

So I've written macros for concatenating its arguments to form a new token:

```
#define uart_is_enabled(i)      (UCSR ## i ## B)
#define uart_putchar(i, c)      UDR ## i = c
```

**Note**: here I'm using UART registers but that's only an example, I'm not trying to make a UART work, I have already code for it, which I want to enhance.

**EDIT**: For the curious, here's a definition of a register such as UCSR0B, as per Atmel library:

```
#ifndef __SFR_OFFSET
#  if __AVR_ARCH__ >= 100
#    define __SFR_OFFSET 0x00
#  else
#    define __SFR_OFFSET 0x20
#  endif
#endif

#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) _MMIO_BYTE((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)

#define UCSR0B  _SFR_IO8(0x25)
```

Now I'd like to try templates classes to work with those macros without resorting to specialization for each possible index:

```
template <const unsigned index>
class Uart
{
public:
    static bool is_enabled() { return uart_is_enabled(index); }
    static void putchar(uint8_t) { uart_putchar(index, c); }
};
```

Of course with `uart<0>` or `uart<1>` or any `unsigned int` for the template argument, I get an error message like this one:

```
 error: 'UCSRindexB' was not declared in this scope
```

This is because macro arguments are "evaluated" (please grant me a pedantic pardon for using an improper term) before template argument values are compiled, if my understanding is correct. Is there a way to make this work anyway?

---

**EDIT** : Although [Phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45391658/4113344) 100% addresses my question directly, I changed my mind and opted for a different approach. I view C/C++ a language in which you need to be verbose, i.e. it is best to declare all the cases you want to manage. There are situations, like this, cutting corners is likely to produce more cumbersome code — this is but my opinion, of course, YMMV.

As a consequence I implemented some form of hardware abstraction through [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): I defined as many hardware driver classes as there are many different UARTs in Atmel processors I use — I'm quite fortunate there aren't as many UART types in Atmel micro-controllers as the number of models.

Here's an example with a LIN/UART driver class:

```
// lin.h (excerpt)
// Auto-detect the one and only serial interface (set UART mode)

#ifdef LINDAT
/*
 * UART0 driver — for microcontroller which UART module is shared
 * with LIN, e.g. ATmega64M1
 */
struct uart0
{
    static INLINE void power_on() { power_lin_enable(); }
    static INLINE void power_off() { power_lin_disable(); }

    static INLINE void enable() { uart_enable(); }
    static INLINE void disable() { uart_disable(); }

    ...

    static void reset();
};

#endif
```

Here's an example for microcontrollers that define 1 or more UART modules:

```
// uart.h (excerpt)
// Auto-detect first serial interface aka U[S]ART0

#ifdef UDR0
struct uart0
{
    static INLINE void power_on() { power_usart0_enable(); }
    static INLINE void power_off() { power_usart0_disable(); }

    static INLINE void enable() { uart_enable(0); }
    static INLINE void disable() { uart_disable(0); }

    ...
};

#endif
```

Note I'm still using the C macros I've introduced above in this post to generalize register handling... although some tend to become quite difficult to read, I admit.

Then I wrote a template class (actually an interface class), which argument is the driver class, from which the interface class inherits.

```
// Generic UART wrapper. Comes with a circular input buffer
template <class driver>
class tty : public driver
{
protected:
    ...

public:
    static void putchar(char) { driver::putchar(c); }
    static void power_off()
    {
        driver::disable();
        driver::power_off();
    }
    ...
};
```

Controller-specific header files are included according to detected register names:

```
#if defined(UDR0) || defined(UDR1) || defined(UDR)
#include <drv/uart.h>
#endif

#ifdef LINDAT
#include <drv/lin.h>
#endif
```

With this approach driver members, which are specific to the architecture I'm compiling for are exposed through the interface class. It allows me to write relatively generic code for as many processors as I want to support for a single application:

```
typedef serio tty<uart0>; // same code for ATmega328p, ATmega64M1, ATtiny1634...
serio::putchar('a');
```

I can also write very-specific code if I want to dedicate my application to a specific micro-controller. I just have to use arch-specific driver members.

For the generic approach, by convention, all of my driver classes must expose a certain number of common members for that concept to work but it needs to be done only once, i.e. when adding support for a new microcontroller. This is indeed some kind of repetitive task (cf. my point about "verbosity"), I mean type code that (almost) looks the same over and over (rinse/repeat with every controller you want support for) but in the end this is the flexibility I want.

I've also checked the generated assembly code and I can confirm the optimizer is doing a rather great job, especially when and where I ask it to inline code.

Comment: The short and only answer is "no". It's simply not possible to use the value of e.g. `index` in a macro.

Comment: And what does `UCSR0B;` in the code? Is it a variable?

Comment: Preprocessing happens before parsing `Uart` as a template and performs only basic text substitution.

Comment: Ok, too bad. I guess I'll have to stick with specialization then, ditching my macros as they'll be useless in that case. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code would work as desired. As macro are evaluate first, you have to create your template specialization manually for each register.

```
// Simulate register names (to test on any compiler)...
static bool UCSR0B;
static bool UCSR1B;

static char UDR0;
static char UDR1;
```

The same macro as is original post can still be useful

```
#define uart_is_enabled(i)      (UCSR ## i ## B)
#define uart_putchar(i, c)      UDR ## i = c
```

Then we declare a template. Here I use an empty class. Your default implementation might be different.

```
template <const unsigned index>
class Uart
{
};
```

At this point, I use a macro to define specialization for all registers.

```
// Macro that define a template specialization for a specific UART
#define UART(index) \
template <> \
class Uart<index> \
{ \
public: \
    static bool is_enabled() { return uart_is_enabled(index); } \
    static void putchar(uint8_t c) { uart_putchar(index, c); } \
}

// Define Uart<0>, Uart<1>... classes
UART(0);
UART(1);
```

Finally, this is a test program that show that it works as expected

```
// Test program
void test()
{
    Uart<0>::is_enabled();
    Uart<1>::is_enabled();
    // Uart<2>::is_enabled();   // Would not compile

    Uart<0>::putchar('a');
    Uart<1>::putchar('b');
    // Uart<2>::putchar('c'); // Would not compile
}
```

Comment: Thank! I hadn't thought of that, obviously! That's a nice way to make specialization kind of like semi-automatic. I like that.